# Using Google's Navigation Drawer example to change fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using the sample Navigation Drawer code to develop a app

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

And I want to change the fragment to listview or map...etc

but the sample use image

I would like to know how I can change a new fragment instead of showing an image?

Here is the onCreateView function code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
    int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
    String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

    int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                    "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
    ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
    getActivity().setTitle(planet);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see image is itself loads in PlanetFragment. So according to your logic you can set any fragment attached with navigation drawer list item position. its not necessity to show anything in a single fragment.  
In the method `private void selectItem(int position) {}` has parameter position so using that `int` load different fragments.

```
 Fragment fragment;
 if(position==0)
 {
   fragment = new FirstFragment();
 }else if(position==1)
 {
   fragment = new SecondFragment();
 }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I finally made it!